# ZeroMQ+Java binding Windows

Tags: java, zeromq

Does anyone have instructions for installing zeromq on windows without Visual C++?

Comment: I've found links to pre-compiled binaries on [Installation ZeroMQ on Windows](http://www.zeromq.org/docs:windows-installations/comments/show#post-1276562) page. See comment from *pieterh* on 8 Oct 2011.

Comment: If you plan on developing in Java, you can use the zeromq pure Java implementation on Windows, get the 0.3.0-SNAPSHOT.... https://github.com/zeromq/jeromq